# Packagist no update after Push to GH

Tags: composer-php, packagist

I'm new to Composer/Packagist. So bare with. After careful reviewing ALL the Composer documentation (which IMHO quite verbose but flawes on the details). And going through [Azraar Azward good article](https://medium.com/@mazraara/create-a-composer-package-and-publish-3683596dec45) I'm still stuck.

Created GitHub public repo and Packagist package. I can use it in a test but autoupdate is not working. I've setup auto update according to the Packagist description, the repo is public but after pushing to GitHub the Packager does not get the updates.

In GitHub under WebHooks I followed these steps:

```
Do not want to log in via GitHub and grant us webhook configuration access?

You can configure a GitHub webhook manually by using the following values:

    Payload URL: https://packagist.org/api/github?username=theking2
    Content Type: application/json
    Secret: your Packagist API Token
    Which events? Just the push event is enough.
```

In Packager however it is still displayed as `(Not Auto-Updated, Needs Attention)` but it is not awefully clear what kind of attention it needs.

I've setup Git push to a myriad of (Plesk) websites so I get the idea how it is supposed to work. What is confusing that I find nowhere which trunk Packagist is using. I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: I'm seeing the same. Packagists's [About page](https://packagist.org/about#how-to-update-packages) has a few steps for what to do when seeing this message. It's near useless though. "log in via GitHub again to make sure you grant us the required permissions" - which permissions?! I guess the ones that are requested with using GitHub SSO. Still, it's basically saying, "log out and back in again". Even the "manual" GitHub webhook set up is incredibly vague. There's really nothing useful there.

Comment: My issue went away after I did three things. 1. I deleted my package on Packagist. 2. added a "repository" section to my `composer.json`, eg. `"repository": {"type": "git", "url": "https://github.com/[repo]/[package].git"}`. 3. I made a git tag form and a GitHub Release for it. I then resubmitted the package in Packagist obviously. I have no idea which if any of these fixed the issue. ‾\_(ツ)_/‾